# How do conditional pardons at the end of a president's term work?

Tags: united-states, pardon

Looking at the [list](https://www.newsweek.com/donald-trump-73-late-pardons-presidents-last-minute-clemency-list-1562933) of Trump's final pardons, I notice that two of the pardons are conditional.  My question is, what happens if the conditions for a conditional pardon either aren't met until during next president's term, or they are broken during the next president's term?

Could the new president decline to execute the pardon even if the conditions were met?  Could he maintain the pardon even if the conditions were broken?

I'm interested in the mechanics in general, not just Trump's pardons.

Answer (score 4):

For example, Stephen Odzer is a recipient of a "conditional pardon". Mr Odzer is a convicted fraudster and received an 18-month sentence and a restitution order. However, he has already been released from prison. The pardon requires Mr Odzer to pay the remainder of his restitution order. But the pardon does restore civil rights to Mr Odzer, such as voting rights, posession of a firearm or allow him to be considered for jobs that require a position of trust.  If Mr Odzer breaks this condition then the pardon is void and he would lose those rights.

The pardon is now granted and is effective unless Mr Odzer breaks the conditions.  Biden can't reverse it.

Comment: Could you cite any authority for why this is the case?